# autoplay videos in lightbox programs

Tags: youtube, fancybox

Hi im looking at intergrating fancybox with a youtube video but I want it so when you visit a website it pops up and automaticly plays without clicking a link.

for example. if you visit http://www.turkspoultry.com/ i want a video to suddenly popup and start playing about the history of turks poultry.

any ideas?

Comment: sorted. Message me if you are curious but I cannot add an answer until 8 more hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to figure out the same thing earlier, and I ended up ditching youtube. As far as I know, there is no way to autostart youtube videos, I could be wrong.

What I did is I loaded the video into  [EasyHTML5Video](http://easyhtml5video.com/) and it spat out 4 different video files and an index.html, I then put that index in a sub folder and I called the video/page in fancy box using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        'width': 745,
        'height': 565,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'href': 'Mylinktothehtmlpage'
    });
});
```

That auto opens the page and as long as you check mark AutoPlay when you are in EasyHTML5Video then all should work!

Comment: Yeah I managed to autoplay youtube mate heres my iframe code from the embeded video on my site

<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/U6Lp558wST8?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


notice the autoplay=1 on the end of the youtube URL

Comment: So I stand corrected :) We all learn something everyday, and that's deffinatly something I will be keeping in my arsenal!